Python Code to calculate MD5 hash from an image from memory not hard disk
I am opening an image. changing its pixels attributes in a loop and calculate each new images hash.
but when a pixel changes in an image I have to save it to hard disk then read new image and calculate hash.
How can I calculate image hash without saving it on hard disk
from PIL import Image
import hashlib as hashing

# original file path
img_path = "./images/A10ne_blackGold"
pil_image = Image.open(img_path+".png")
pil_pix = pil_image.load()

for i in range (5):
    pil_pix[0, 0] = (i, i, i)
    new_img_path = img_path+str(i)+".png"
    pil_image.save(new_img_path)
    with open(new_img_path, "rb") as f:
        hash0 = hashing.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()
        print(i," Hash: ", hash0, "\n")


now I want somehow delete that pil_image.save(new_img_path) part as it makes huge time lag in code!
this means no need to open png file again and just read it from memory. I am not sure if it is possible.
Please consider that if i want to save png file its hash has to be same as the hash I calculate from image on memory.

The PNG file contains compressed data, not pixel values. You can use Image.getdata to get the in-memory pixel values but the hash you generate won't match the binary file's hash
